# Adobe Flex/AIR iOS App - Launching application from the browser while the app is suspended in the background

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

I've got an iOS app developed in Adobe AIR, and the user is able to launch the app via a browser, using a custom URL scheme.

Basically, the user will almost always use the browser to launch the app, and the browser passes in the user's session information as an argument. When the app starts up, this session data is used to load up a session for that particular user.

However, the user has to be able to switch sessions whenever they want to, via the browser. When the user switches to Safari (placing the app in the background) and clicks a different session link, the app comes back into the foreground, but the InvokeEvent does not fire.

When the app is not running, there's no issue, because the InvokeEvent is fired, and the argument can be read.

How do I pass data to the app from the browser (via an argument or otherwise) when the app is already suspended in the background?

By the way, setting UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to true is not an option. Management does not like the extra load time required when this is set to true. Because if a user goes to check their e-mail or use Safari, and then returns to the app, the app starts up from scratch, and the user has to wait for the splash screen to go away, and then for their session data (which is stored in memory) to be verified by the server. Setting this flag to false makes that extra wait go away, but now consequently, the user cannot switch to a different session.

This never used to be an issue, because originally, we had UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend set to true.

Can someone please help me out with this? Is there another event that I can use?

Comment: Anyone? This is still an issue...the InvokeEvent fires, but the arguments parameter is null. Can anyone help me with this?